Can I create rules/shortcuts to configure the directory in which GNOME Terminal tabs open?
By default, when I open a new tab in the gnome terminal, the new tab will be in the same directory as the tab where I issued the command.
Is there any way to set rules or shortcuts to make the new tab either in the same directory or in $HOME?

Edit your .bashrc file in the $HOME directory and add the following lines at the end of the file:
# Always open Home directory
cd $HOME

Now whenever you open a new tab, it will change the directory to the $HOME directory.
But if you want a new tab with the $HOME directory at certain times, then it can be achieved by two methods:
Creating Aliases
Add the following aliases to your shell configuration (~/.bashrc) file:
alias newtabhome='gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="$HOME"'

Run the command newtabhome and a new tab will open up with $HOME directory
Using Keyboard Shortcuts
Open your Ubuntu Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.
Click on the + option and add the command as a shortcut:
gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory="$HOME"


Give your desired shortcut key to run this command (I used Ctrl+Alt+N)
Now use this command to launch a new terminal or tab with $HOME directory.

EDIT: As @vanadium mentioned, a simple cd command will change the current directory to the $HOME directory. So you don't have to create extra rules or shortcuts to achieve this.

Nice anser, but the OP also seems to ask if it is possible to "set rules or shortcuts" to create a new tab either in the same directory or in home. I do not think so but then a simple "cd" is a "shortcut" that can move the user to $HOME after creating the tab. You may want to add this to your answer (unless other approaches do exist).

@vanadium Thank you for pointing that out. I have added a new solution that suits the OP's question better. I have also included your comment on my answer.

Thanks, the alias method works well for me. The custom shortcut however opens a new windows instead of a new tab on the current terminal.

@Ajay, very good suggestions. For creating a new terminal window, this would work very well, but indeed, the --tab command will add a tab to the current window only when the command is issued on the prompt.

Note that adding cd / cd "$HOME" (you should quote $HOME) to ~/.bashrc will also make Bash behave the same in every other terminal / TTY, which may or may not be desirable

You can define two profiles with different custom commands, one with e.g. env -C ... to switch to your home directory and start the shell there. In the headerbar you have a dropdown arrow that allows you to open a new terminal with the profile of your choice.
However, just using the standard shortcut keys (or whatever your preferred method is) to open a new terminal, and possibly having to type cd<enter> to take you to your home, is probably faster and more convenient.
